# Optimal regularity of polynomial interpolators

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, approximation-theory

**Definitions**

1. We define the "complexity" of any *polynomial function* $p:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ as $m\binom{n+\deg(p)}{n}$ *(i.e the dimension of $\oplus_{i=1}^m\,\mathbb{R}[X_1,\dots,X_n]_d=:\operatorname{Pol}_{\deg(p)}(n,m)$)*.
2. Consider the closed Euclidean ball about some $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ of radius $r>0$, denoted by $\overline{B(x_0,r)}$.  Define the norm on any smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ by
   $$
   \|f\|_{C^{k,1}:x_0,r}:=
   \max_{i=1 \leq m}
   \max_{| \beta | \leq k} \sup_{x\in\Omega} \left |D^\beta f_i (x) \right |
   +
   \sup_{x\in \overline{B(x_0,r)}}\,\max_{| \beta | = k} \left | D^\beta f_i(x)  \right |,
   $$
   where $f=(f_1,\dots,f_m)$.

---

**Problem**

Fix a positive integer $T,n$, and $m$.

Let $x_1,\dots,x_T$ be a set of distinct points in $\overline{B(x_0,r)}$, for some $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and some $r>0$, and let $y_1,\dots,y_T$ be a set of (not necessarily distinct) points in $\mathbb{R}^m$.  Let $d^{\star}$ be the smallest integer for which there exists some polynomial function $p \in \oplus_{i=1}^m\,\mathbb{R}[X_1,\dots,X_n]_d$ satisfying
$$
p(x_t) = y_t \qquad \mbox{ for } t=1,\dots,T \qquad (1)
.
$$

Are there known (sharp) bounds for:
$$
\inf_{p(x_t)=y_t,\,t=1,\dots,T;\, p\in 
\operatorname{Pol}_{d^{\star}}(n,m)
}\, \|f\|_{C^{k,1}:x_0,r}
$$

This seems to be a simplified version of the Whitney extension theorem when data comes from a finite set and we only consider minimal-degree polynomial extensions (instead of all smooth extensions).